# Aggregate counting logical values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hello friend I am not friendly with mongodb aggregation I want is that I have array of object that contains subjects with its score for each question and I am using node js so I want is that full calculation with mongo query  if possible that include subject name with its total score and count of attempt and not attempt my Json Array is as bellow

```
{
    "examId": ObjectId("597367af7d8d3219d88c4341"),
    "questionId": ObjectId("597368207d8d3219d88c4342"),
    "questionNo": 1,
    "subject": "Reasoning Ability",
    "yourChoice": "A",
    "correctMark": "1",
    "attempt": true,
    "notAttempt": false,
}
```

here in object one field is for correct marks subject are different an I want an output like

```
|Subject Name | Total attempts | total not attempts | total score |
| A           | 5              | 3                  | 10          |
| B           | 10             | 5                  | 25          |
```

I am trying with aggregation but not done yet I have tried this query

```
db.examscores.aggregate([
  { $group:{
    _id:"$examId",
    score: { $sum: '$correctMark' },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }}
])
```

Any one has idea how to achieve this type of output.
and if another way to achieve this using node than also good.

Comment: What output are you getting from your current one? And what your used for `$correctMark` you can use similar approach for `$attempt`, you would need to use `$cond` and `$eq`

Comment: I am getting count of total records,score : 0  and correctMark is my field name that contain score of each question that user has given

Comment: You are basically looking for [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to either return `1` or `0` depending on the logical value that is already stored, or by some other logical evaluation. You need to note that as your document currently stands `"correctMark"` actually is holding "strings" and not numeric values. If you attempt to use `$sum` with a "string" the result will always be `0`. So you need to fix your data as a priority.

Comment: I have changed in to number now it is giving me count but now I want that count of attempts and not attempts which are Boolean values with subjects name

Comment: Is it possible to see a sample dataset so we can write the pipelines for aggregation ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this here is my query

```
[
 { $match: { subject:'Reasoning Ability' } },
 {
   $group:
     {
       _id:{id:"$examId",subject:'$subject'},
       totalAttempt: { $sum:  {$cond : [ "$attempt", 1, 0 ]} },
       totalNotAttempt: { $sum:  {$cond : [ "$notAttempt", 1, 0 ]} },
       markedForReview:{ $sum:  {$cond : [ "$markedForReview", 1, 0 ]} },
       answerAndMarkedForReview:{ $sum:  {$cond : [ "$answerAndMarkedForReview", 1, 0 ]} },
       score: { $sum: '$correctMark' },
       count: { $sum: 1 }
     }
 }
```

]